# get a parameter from ui-router state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular View who have Add and Edit Action Like:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button id="agregar" type="submit" class="btn blue btn-lg" ng-click="nuevo();">Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button id="editar" type="submit" class="btn blue btn-lg" ng-click="editar();">Edit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button id="eliminar" type="submit" class="btn blue btn-lg" ng-click="eliminar();">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller of actions are:

```
function nuevo() {
     $state.go("root.detalleregistros", { tipo: "nuevo" });
}

function editar() {
     $state.go("root.detalleregistros", { tipo: "edicion"}); 
}
```

As you can see I redirect to same view `root.detallregistros` and need to get the 'tipo' value. So I could execute the corresponding function.

```
function insertar() {           
    apiService.post("../../api/Catalogo/AddCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID, 
      function(res) {
            // my code
         });
}
```

and if it come with tipo:edicion execute other action

Comment: Check ui-router stateParams

Comment: I upload it @yBrodsky

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You need to use $stateParams, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

Comment: This is how I route it.  As @Andrea comment I add, `params: {
                tipo: "nuevo",
            }` @yBrodsky

Answer (score 0):

You can use in your service an associative array like this:

```js
var apiUrlMap = {
  new: "newApiPath",
  edit: "editApiPath",
  delete: "deleteApiPath",
};
```

and then before the service call you can extract the correct api url path according to the view parameter, i.e. `var apiUrl = apiUrlMap[tipo];` and then build your complete api url.

Hope this could help you

Comment: Service you refer as my state? can you help me there? I´m really new in angular I post my .state into my question

Comment: With service i mean the framework conponent used in order to perform backend calls. Buf maybe you nave ho specify more clearly what is the question purpose because My solution does not concearn the view parameter passing, maybe i am off topic

Answer (score 0):

you can expose its value using $stateParams.tipo and don't forget to inject the $stateParams service in your controller. Good luck

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    if($stateParams.tipo === 'nuevo') {
        // your corresponding code 
    }
    else if($stateParams.tipo === 'edicion') {
        // your corresponding code
    }
    else if($stateParams.tipo === 'eliminar') {
        // your corresponding code
    }
    else {
        console.log("unexpected tipo value");
    }
})
```

Comment: @Gerardo I hope that would help you